# How to use RecyclerView inside widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I am learning Xamarin android.

I have created one base activity which will generate slide in menu for each activity.

I have one MyBills.axml file which has following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my MyBillsActivity.cs file code.

```
public class MyBillsActivity : BaseActivity
{
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    protected override int LayoutResource
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.Layout.MyBills;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawerLayout = this.FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();


        // Create your application here
    }
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start);
                return true;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now when MyBills.axml page get loads, it throws following error. this is because following code return null value

```
 drawerLayout = this.FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can someone please help me why it is throws error?

NOTE: same code will work fine, if I will remove following code from mybills.axml file

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of putting the RecyclerView directly in your layout put a  Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment and inflate it in your activity, then in your fragment code setup your RecycleView

in my case in my main activity i have a ViewPager with tabs

```
private void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    TabAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
    adapter.AddFragment(new Tab1MainFragment(), "Tab1");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Tab2MainFragment(), "Tab2");

    viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

in my fragment class in OnCreateView i set up the RecicleView

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    recyclerView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Tab1Layout, container, false) as RecyclerView;

    SetUpRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    return recyclerView;
}
```

and this is my fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Tab1RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

that recycles this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```